# Android - spitting bitmap results to low quality

Tags: android, bitmap, gradient

My goal is to create a half-oval gradient image. I create a gradient Drawable which afterwards is converted to a bitmap and cut in half to get my final shape which shows at the right of the picture.

I have doubts about if this is the best way to go about that so feel free to recommend other approaches.

The problem is that the quality is low after splitting the bitmap.You can see that the edges of the half gradient are pixelized. This happens at the point of splitting the bitmap. 
What should I do to retain the initial quality?

```
//create gradient drawable
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(orientation,new int[] {firstColor, secondColor});
gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);

//convert drawable to bitmap
int width=imageView.getLayoutParams().width;
int height=imageView.getLayoutParams().height;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);

//cut bitmap in half
bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, width/2, 0,  width/2, height);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageView..setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

[image]

Comment: that problem is from scaling the bitmap ScaleType.FIT_XY

Comment: you were right thank you! i changed  width=imageView.getLayoutParams().width; to  width=2*imageView.getLayoutParams().width; and now the quality is the same as the original

Comment: Is this though the best way to produce the final result? converting the drawable to bitmap and then proccessing it seems too much computing. Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Well if you want effeciency then create a 9patch image.. it is much more faster than calculating gradients